# How to use caption in a verbatim environment?

Tags: captions, verbatim

I'd like to put a caption under a snippets of code, similar to how one would do with a figure or a table. Just cant seem to figure out how, because putting `\caption` inside `verbatim` produces verbatim what I wrote, duh :). Putting it just below ends up being a paragraph with no association to the verbatim block.

In effect I want the snippet below to look like a verbatim block of text followed by a distinct looking description so it doesn't look like it's just the main text body similar to how an image caption works.

```
\begin{verbatim}
SDSSJ1206+4332
-0.664,.0137,1.748,.028
#1.320,0.147,5.999,0.148
#-2.052,0.200,2.397,0.152
A,0,0.11,0,0.01,18.05,.02
B,-0.098,0.006,2.894,.009,18.38,.02
\end{verbatim}
\caption{Behold this fully functional input file.}
```

Update:

Trying to get Werners solution to work. I tried putting his solution into my existing document and all I get is two horizontal rules with the title on top.
Putting his solution into a new document works, so I think it's in the preamble somewhere. Below is what my main documents looks like right now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MA.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{myverbatim}[1][]{%
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    captionpos=b,
    #1
  }%
}{}



\title{MAThe}
\author{Michkov}
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What what would you like the caption's *label type* to be -- Figure, Table, Code Block, Input File, Algorithm, or something else? Is it important to denote that it's in some (virtual or real) file? Should the verbatim chunk and its caption be allowed to float (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word)?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand the question about label type, but since it's an input file I guess Input File is the right one. What I want to do is go through the verbatim section line by line later and explain what each bit does.

Regarding floating, this needs to be in where I put it in the text.

Comment: Here's what @Mico meant: `\caption` in a `figure` produces `Figure X:`. `\caption` in a `table` produces `Table Y:`. Do you want something different to this, as in `Code Block Z:` or `Input File Z:`, or `Algorithm Z:`, or something else?

Comment: Ah I understand. What I want is a visually distinct section of text without `Figure X:` or similar. One that looks like it belongs to the verbatim block not the paragraph following it.

Comment: @Michkov: Remember, visually distinct is vague (or subjective). *You* need to decide what you mean by that. How about a rule across the column width, followed by the `verbatim` text, followed by a small gap, then the "caption", then another rule. That to me would separate the `verbatim` code block and its accompanying "caption" from the rest of the text.

Comment: @Werner. Thanks for that suggestion I think that is the quickest way get it to look the way I want it to. I'm off to toy around with lines and rulers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use some of the functionality provided by [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,lipsum}

\lstnewenvironment{myverbatim}[1][]{%
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=tb,
    #1
  }%
}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{myverbatim}[title={Behold this fully functional input file.}]
SDSSJ1206+4332
-0.664,.0137,1.748,.028
#1.320,0.147,5.999,0.148
#-2.052,0.200,2.397,0.152
A,0,0.11,0,0.01,18.05,.02
B,-0.098,0.006,2.894,.009,18.38,.02
\end{myverbatim}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be the ideal solution if I could get it to work. Even copying it over results in the verbatim text not showing up. All I get is the lines and title.

Also is it possible to have the title below or unumber the caption instead?

Comment: @Michkov: You can add the option `captionpos=b` within the `\lstset` settings. You'd have to supply more detail in order to see why things are failing on your end.

Comment: Check the top post I updated it with my preamble.

Comment: @Michkov: I can't replicate your problem, even with your preamble. Things work on my end as expected.

Comment: Figured out why it wouldn't work. I was running in overleafs draft mode all the time and it appears that it doens't fully process the new environment. All I'd get were the two lines and the title without the actual verbatim text. Switching to full compile mode fixed that.

Works now, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `verbatimbox` to capture verbatim in an hbox. It can be output with or without an `\fbox` border.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,caption,float,lipsum}
\newfloat{Code}
\captionsetup{Code}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{verbbox}
SDSSJ1206+4332
-0.664,.0137,1.748,.028
#1.320,0.147,5.999,0.148
#-2.052,0.200,2.397,0.152
A,0,0.11,0,0.01,18.05,.02
B,-0.098,0.006,2.894,.009,18.38,.02
\end{verbbox}
{\centering
\theverbbox
\captionof{Code}{Behold this fully functional input file.}\par
}
{\centering
\fbox{\theverbbox}
\captionof{Code}{Behold this fully functional input file.}\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]